# make order in json decode

Tags: php, sql-order-by, json

```
 [
        {
            "id": "123",
            "name": "aaa"
        },
        {
            "id": "567",
            "name": "bbb"
        },
        {
            "id": "469",
            "name": "ccc"
        },
        {
            "id": "577",
            "name": "ddd"
        },
        {
            "id": "388",
            "name": "eee"
        }
]
```

How to make a order when json decode?

```
$data = json_decode($json);
foreach ($data as $row) {    
    sort($row)?
}
```

I need all the decode data make an `order by id`.

Final data output: `"name": "aaa",  "name": "eee", "name": "ccc", "name": "bbb", "name": "ddd"`

Comment: The output you expect is impossible because every key can only be associated with one value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort).

```
$data = json_decode($json);
usort($data, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a->id == $b->id) {
        return 0;
    }
    return $a->id < $b->id ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Or, if you're using PHP < 5.3, you need to define the comparison function, since the support for anonymous functions was added in PHP 5.3.

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a->id == $b->id) {
        return 0;
    }
    return $a->id < $b->id ? -1 : 1;
}
$data = json_decode($json);
usort($data, 'cmp');
```

This would sort the array. After that, if you want to create an array with only the `name` values, you could do that with a [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach).

```
$result = array();
foreach ($data as $entry) {
    $result[] = array('name' => $entry->name);
}
```

The `$result` variable will now contain:

```
array(array('name' => 'aaa'),
      array('name' => 'eee'),
      array('name' => 'ccc'),
      array('name' => 'bbb'),
      array('name' => 'ddd'));
```

Then, to encode the result as JSON again, you can call [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode).

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

This will output a string similar to:

```
[{"name": "aaa"},
 {"name": "eee"},
 {"name": "ccc"},
 {"name": "bbb"},
 {"name": "ddd"}]
```

Comment: You can also compare values with return strcmp($a->id, $b->id);

Comment: Wouldn't it be `$entry->name` instead of `$entry['name']` ?

Comment: @Radu, Thanks, you lost one `)` in `usort($data, function($a, $b)) {` but although I add it, still caused `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION` in that line.

Comment: @cj333, this works in PHP >= 5.3. What version of PHP are you using? Also, there's no need for an extra `)`. The `usort()` function takes a function as the second argument. Edited answer to add a pre-PHP 5.3 version of the example code.

Comment: OH, soory for the extra `)` my version is `5.2` now.